# AnyEvent tcp server-client example for localhost hangs when not using TLS

Tags: perl, anyevent

While debugging a failed test for [AnyEvent](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent) on Windows, I created the following script based on test [80_ssltest.t](https://metacpan.org/source/MLEHMANN/AnyEvent-7.17/t%2F80_ssltest.t):

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use AnyEvent::Socket;
use AnyEvent::Handle;
use AnyEvent::TLS;

my $ctx = AnyEvent::TLS->new( cert_file => $0 );
my $server_done = AnyEvent->condvar;
my $client_done = AnyEvent->condvar;
my $server_port = AnyEvent->condvar;
my $host = "127.0.0.1";

my $server = tcp_server(
    $host,
    undef,   # service: must be either a service name or a numeric port number
             #   (or 0 or undef, in which case an ephemeral port will be used).
             #
    sub { # This is the accept callback..
        my ($fh, $host, $port) = @_;

        say "server_accept";
        my $hd; $hd = AnyEvent::Handle->new(
            #tls      => "accept",
            #tls_ctx  => $ctx,
            fh       => $fh,
            timeout  => 8,
            on_error => sub {
                say "server_error <$_[2]>";
                $server_done->send; undef $hd;
            },
            on_eof   => sub {
                say "server_eof";
                $server_done->send; undef $hd;
            }
        );

        $hd->push_read (
            line => sub {
                say "server got line <$_[1]>";
            }
        );

    },  # end of accept callback..
    sub {  # This is the prepare callback
        say "server_listen";
        $server_port->send ($_[2]);
   }
);

my $port = $server_port->recv;   # At this point the server should be listening...
my $hd; $hd = AnyEvent::Handle->new(
    connect    => [$host, $port],
    #tls        => "connect",
    #tls_ctx    => $ctx,
    timeout    => 8,
    on_connect => sub {
        say "client_connect";
    },
    on_error   => sub {
        say "client_error <$_[2]>";
        $client_done->send; undef $hd;
    },
    on_eof     => sub {
        say "client_eof";
        $client_done->send; undef $hd;
    }
);

$hd->push_write ("1\n");
say "Sleeping..";
sleep 1;

$hd->on_drain (sub {
   say "client_drain";
   $client_done->send;
   undef $hd;  # For some reason this does not send EOF to the server
});

say "Waiting for client done..";
$client_done->recv;
say "Waiting for server done..";
$server_done->recv;


__END__
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

This script hangs (Ubuntu 20.04, perl version 5.30), but if I use TLS handshake (uncomment the lines in the code with `tls` and `tls_ctx`) it works fine.

The output without TLS is:

```
server_listen
Sleeping..
Waiting for client done..
client_drain
server_accept
Waiting for server done..
server got line <1>
server_error <Connection timed out>
```

The output with TLS (after uncommenting the 4 lines starting with `tls` and `tls_ctx`) is:

```
server_listen
Sleeping..
Waiting for client done..
client_connect
server_accept
client_drain
Waiting for server done..
server got line <1>
server_eof
```

- Note that `on_connect` is not called (`client_connect` is missing in the output) when not using TLS,
- Even if the client is not connected when not using TLS, the server receives the data and prints `server got line <1>`... Very strange.

Any idea what is the problem when not using TLS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, you are not reading from the socket/handle. Without reading from the socket, there is no way detect an EOF condition.

The reason why you get different behaviour with TLS is that TLS does not emulate socket semantics and AnyEvent::Handle must essentially always read, even if you don't have explicit read requests, therefore it will detect the EOF condition instantly.

You can check for this by adding an on_read handler, e.g. after or before your push_read in the server:

```
$hd->push_read (sub { });
```

With this present, it should behave more or less the same with or without TLS.

Comment: Thanks for answering this! Strangely, it only works if I replace your `$hd->push_read (sub { });` with `$hd->on_read (sub { });`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent::Handle):

> Note that, unlike requests in the read queue, an `on_read` callback
> doesn't mean you require some data: if there is an EOF and there are
> outstanding read requests then an error will be flagged. With an
> `on_read` callback, the `on_eof` callback will be invoked.

This gives a clue that I need an `on_read` callback in order for the `on_eof` callback to be called. I tried to change the server to:

```
my $server = tcp_server(
    $host,
    undef,   # service: must be either a service name or a numeric port number
             #   (or 0 or undef, in which case an ephemeral port will be used).
             #
    sub { # This is the accept callback..
        my ($fh, $host, $port) = @_;

        say "server_accept";
        my $hd; $hd = AnyEvent::Handle->new(
            fh       => $fh,
            timeout  => 5,
            on_error => sub {
                say "server_error <$_[2]>";
                $server_done->send; undef $hd;
            },
            on_eof   => sub {
                say "server_eof";
                $server_done->send; undef $hd;
            }
        );
        $hd->on_read(sub{ say "server on_read() callback"});
        $hd->push_read (
            line => sub {
                say "server got line <$_[1]>";
            }
        );

    },  # end of accept callback..
    sub {  # This is the prepare callback
        say "server_listen";
        $server_port->send ($_[2]);
   }
);
```

The output is now:

```
server_listen
Sleeping..
Waiting for client done..
client_drain
server_accept
Waiting for server done..
server got line <1>
server_eof
```

so it works! (I still wonder why the client `on_connect` is not run, i.e. "client connect" does not show). Also notice that the `on_read` callback is not run since the line "server on_read() callback" is not output.

See also [Why isn't on_eof called in this AnyEvent::Handle example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24373840/2173773)